# Represent rejection region using p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

Let's say we have some level $\alpha$ test (*more precisely, family of tests parametrized by $\alpha \in (0,1)$*), $\delta(\mathbf{x},\alpha)$. This means
$$\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_\theta(\mathbf{X} \in R_\alpha) \le \alpha, \quad \forall \alpha \in (0,1),$$
where $R_\alpha = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}: \delta(\mathbf{x},\alpha) = 1\}$ is the critical region (here $\mathcal{X}$ is the sample space, usually $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^n$).

Let's assume that this test is also non-randomized and monotonic (this requirement is met for most tests used in practice). Then it has a valid p-value, i.e.
$$\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_\theta(p(\mathbf{X}) \le \alpha) \le \alpha, \quad \forall \alpha \in (0,1),$$
where $p(\mathbf{X}) = \inf\{u \in (0,1): \mathbf{X} \in R_u\}$ is the p-value. We often refer to tests with a valid p-value as valid tests.

**My question is the following: given that we have a valid level $\alpha$ test, does this mean that its critical region can be represented as the following set:**

$$R_\alpha = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}: p(\mathbf{x}) \le \alpha\}, \quad \forall \alpha \in (0,1)$$

---

**P.S.** This seems to be true because the event $\{\mathbf{X} \in R_\alpha\}$ seems to be equivalent to the event $\{p(\mathbf{X}) \le \alpha\}$.

You can say – why do we need such representation (assuming the answer to the question is "yes")? I think it may be useful if we have formula for the p-value but didn't know (or forgot) the formula for the "original" critical region. For example, it is well known fact that the p-value for the two-sided Z-test is $p(\mathbf{x}) = 2 \cdot \Phi(-|Z(\mathbf{x})|)$. Hence, we can write
$$\begin{equation}R_\alpha = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: p(\mathbf{x}) \le \alpha\} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: 2 \cdot \Phi(-|Z(\mathbf{x})|) \le \alpha\} = \\ = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: -|Z(\mathbf{x})| \le z_\frac{\alpha}{2}\} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: |Z(\mathbf{x})| \ge -z_\frac{\alpha}{2}\}
\end{equation}.$$
The last expression is a well known formula for the "original" critical region of the two-sided Z-test.

---

Also Casella and Berger in their book "Statistical inference" in sect.8.3.4 have some kind of inverse statement that a valid test is a level $\alpha$ test:

> If $p(\mathbf{X})$ is a valid p-value, it is easy to construct a level $\alpha$ test based on $p(\mathbf{X})$. The test that rejects $H_0$ if and only if $p(\mathbf{X}) \le \alpha$ is a level $\alpha$ test because of the definition of a valid p-value.

I think that their phrase "the test that rejects $H_0$ if and only if $p(\mathbf{X}) \le \alpha$" is essentially equivalent to the phrase "the test has rejection region $R_\alpha = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}: p(\mathbf{x}) \le \alpha\}$".